# Replace a line that starts with something with something else, via sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a document with about 200 lines. One of these has the following phrase:

```
TCP_IN = "1" "2" "A" "B" "29001" "45000"
```

I want to replace that entire row with this one:

```
TCP_IN = "22, 80, 443, 9000"
```

I tried these regex operations to target the desired phrase and all that comes after it:

```
sed -i 's/^TCP_IN \= (.*)/TCP_IN \= "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' /etc/csf/csf.conf
sed -i 's/TCP_IN \= (.*)/TCP_IN \= "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' /etc/csf/csf.conf
```

What did I do wrong telling the computer "target my phrase `TCP_IN =` and all that comes after it and replace it with the stream I'll give you"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed 's/TCP_IN = "1" "2" "A" "B" "29001" "45000"/TCP_IN = "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' file
```

or

```
sed 's/TCP_IN = .*/TCP_IN = "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' file
```

or

```
sed 's/\(TCP_IN =\) .*/\1 "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' file
```

or use extended regular expressions (`-E`)

```
sed -E 's/(TCP_IN =) .*/\1 "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' file
```

Output:

```
TCP_IN = "22, 80, 443, 9000"
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. I used option 2. I understand it says "this prase and all after it while all is represented by match every character (dot) and all characters (asterisk). I only want to ask Cyrus. Do you think option 3 or 4 are safer than option 2?

Comment: The dot matches a single character, without caring what that character is. The only exception are line break characters. The star quantifier (*) means that the preceding expression can match zero or more times. I can't say much about safety. To avoid wrong hits, I would add `^` to mark start of line: `sed 's/^TCP_IN = .*/TCP_IN = "22, 80, 443, 9000"/' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sed one liner to achieve the same.

```
sed  '/TCP_IN = "1" "2" "A" "B" "29001" "45000"/s/.*/TCP_IN = "22, 80, 443, 9000"/g’ filename
```

output

```
TCP_IN = "22, 80, 443, 9000"
```